# how select grid view row by entering index in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, indexing

I am working on C# asp.net web application .it contains a Grid view,text box and a button.what i want is when i type 1 in text box and enter button then automatically select the first row and directed to another page which contains more details of the selected row
in my code it is possible to redirect to next page by clicking the hyperlink using mouse...but it's not my requirement.
here is my code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtindex" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Height="39px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" Text="go" Width="53px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="acno" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="acno" HeaderText="acno" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="acno" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="acno"  HeaderText="username"     
           DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/details.aspx?acno={0}" Target="_blank"                 DatatextField="username"     SortExpression="username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="rdate" HeaderText="rdate" SortExpression="rdate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:postofficeConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [acno], [username], [rdate] FROM [customer]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(txtindex.Text);
    int aid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Values[0]);

    Response.Redirect("details.aspx?acno{0}");
}
```

details.aspx.cs

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id =int.Parse( Request.QueryString["acno"]);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select acno,username,states,district,fname,lname from customer where acno='"+id+"'",con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text=dr[0].ToString();
            Label2.Text=dr[1].ToString();
            Label3.Text=dr[2].ToString();
            Label4.Text=dr[3].ToString();
            Label5.Text=dr[4].ToString();
            Label6.Text=dr[5].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: be more specific?what you actually want...?

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing? your code for button1_click is not firing or what?

Comment: what i want is when i enter gridview index number in my text box then select the row from grid view with that index number and then  redirected to another page to show more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = int.Parse(txtindex.Text);
int aid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());

Response.Redirect(string.Format("details.aspx?acno={0}", aid));
```

And you better use `int.TryParse` to check user input

```
int index,aid;
if (int.TryParse(txtindex.Text, out index) && 
    int.TryParse((GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()) , out aid))
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("details.aspx?acno={0}", aid));
}
```

Comment: thanks...but  i entered 1 and when redirected to details page it shows Value cannot be null

Comment: can you update the question with page load event of details page?

Comment: have you change this line `Response.Redirect(string.Format("details.aspx?acno={0}", aid));`? and what is the value you get in `details` as `Request.QueryString["acno"]`?

Comment: its working now but when i use the same code  in another grid view its not working...please help me @Damith

Comment: @beoun it is better you ask another question

Comment: i already posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507697/how-to-select-grid-view-row-by-entering-index-in-a-text-box